# Apache Poi SAX Write Empty cells

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

```
 public void processOneSheet(String filename) throws Exception {
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );

    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    // To look up the Sheet Name / Sheet Order / rID,
    //  you need to process the core Workbook stream.
    // Normally it's of the form rId# or rSheet#
    InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId2");
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);
    parser.parse(sheetSource);
    sheet2.close();
    }

    public void processAllSheets(String filename) throws Exception {
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );

    SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

    XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

    Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
    while(sheets.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
        InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
        parser.parse(sheetSource);
        sheet.close();
        System.out.println("end Processing");
    }
}

public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst) throws SAXException {
    XMLReader parser =
        XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(
                "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser"
        );
    ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);
    return parser;
}

   /** 
     * See org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler javadocs 
     */
   private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;

    private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        this.sst = sst;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference

            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        // Process the last contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        if(nextIsString) {
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
            lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;
        }` here
```

my file has the following structure :

```
 A       B       C       D
```

1   text    text    text    text

2   text    text    text    text

im reading the excel file, than im adding some data change and give it as output. 
but sometimes text could be empty, the problem is when writing the excel file it's not taking into consideration the empty cell, and it's fetched with the content of the next cell.
please how can i deal with it ??

Comment: Each cell comes with the cell's reference, so you can easily tell missing cells by the cell's jumping from eg A3 to C3. Why not add logic for that?

Comment: thank you @Gagravarr, but it seems i'm not familiar with this kind of logic,please, can you suggest me something ?

Comment: @Gagravarr actuaaly, i kept looking to this issus, but the problem with cell reference suppose that i know the empty cells before. or, im suppose to look for them during the treaement and fill them with data. any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 3):

Excel files are written "sparsely", excluding cells which aren't used to reduce space. When you're reading the files back, you need to take account of this

If you're using the easy (but memory hungry) UserModel, you can use things like [a MissingCellPolicy](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) to control how these missing cells are handled

If you want to go low level and process it with SAX events, as you seem to, then you need to take care of that yourself. Simply grab the reference of each cell as it goes past, keep track of the last one you saw, and handle any missing ones at that point

Apache POI [has a great example of doing this, in the SAX-powered XLSX to CSV example converter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java). You need to largely follow the same logic, eg

```
private class SheetToCSV implements SheetContentsHandler {
    private boolean firstCellOfRow = false;
    private int currentCol = -1;

    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
            XSSFComment comment) {
        if (firstCellOfRow) {
            firstCellOfRow = false;
        } else {
            output.append(',');
        }

        // Did we miss any cells?
        int thisCol = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();
        int missedCols = thisCol - currentCol - 1;
        for (int i=0; i<missedCols; i++) {
            output.append(',');
        }
        currentCol = thisCol;

        // .... Rest of cell contents handling method goes here ....
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i will follow the example and i will see what it gives

Comment: did you manage to do it? @Johnspecter I'm having the same situation

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario for SAX event based xlsx parser & I simply extended Gagravarr's approach to fit in my requirement i.e in this model , you need to track of which column you processed last so process skipped columns before current column as per your wish & you know that those cells have been blank.

```
@Override
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue) {
    int currentColumnIndex = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();
    for (int columnIndex = previousCol + 1; columnIndex <= currentColumnIndex; ++columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex != currentColumnIndex) {
            setValueInRowObject(columnIndex, "");
        } else {
            setValueInRowObject(columnIndex, formattedValue);
        }
    }
    previousCol = currentColumnIndex;
    }
```

where `previousCol` is an instance field initialized to `-1`  & reset at call of - `startRow` method ,

```
    @Override
        public void startRow(int rowNum) {
        previousCol = -1;
}
```

I basically had certain amount & date columns and I need to populate a warning message  if those columns carry an invalid value & blank is not a valid amount or date. But since `cell` method was not getting called for empty cells so I wasn't able to populate that warning message for that particular cell.